# Pentaho 5: Repository connection window not showing up

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am able to open a Pentaho version 5 Spoon session on my new laptop but when I clicked on Tools -> Repository -> Connect, nothing comes up (no connection window).

However, I am using the same executable on my old laptop and there its working without any issues. I have also downloaded a fresh executable of version 5 on my new laptop but it didn't work as well. I am wondering what could be causing this.

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: May be java version issue.. check on which java you are using in your old laptop and which is installed in new laptop.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the difference as the new laptop has latest version of java. I will download the latest version of Pentaho, which should work.

Comment: I am now using pentaho 8 community edition with jdk 10 and now I am not able to see connect option in the menu when I click tools-> repository,  to create a connection.

Comment: check Pentaho website whether it supports jdk 10 or not... in new version of Pentaho.. at right corner you will find connect option... new version method is changed.. google a bit you will find your answer.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. thanks. A lower version of jdk(8) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Working Hard..  in the comments, I installed jdk8 (I was using jdk10 earlier) and created a new environment variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME as explained in the below URL and added the path accordingly.

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0F0/0G0/020

Regards,
Sachin